# How can I make a curve border like this, using CSS3?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<body>
<style>
div.curve-border{
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J3ny.jpg);
}
</style>
<div class="curve-border"></div>
</body>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J3ny.jpg 
 How to achieve the curve paths of this image.

Comment: the duplicate consider gradient but you can easily change with an image

Comment: I need help with image as well, not easy to replace the gradient with an image.